# Search Item in Wikidata SPARQL by Title ignoring special characters, like regular search

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to find a movie by a title regardless special characters that wiki has in it.

For example I am searching for "Guyver Dark Hero" movie.
Wiki has it under the title "Guyver: Dark Hero".

When I use this query it can't find any thing:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {       
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .       
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .       
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "Guyver Dark Hero" .       
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .       
    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .       
  } 
  {
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424;
          rdfs:label ?itemLabel.
  }
}
LIMIT 1
```

But if I search by "Guyver: Dark Hero", the item will be found.
How can I search just by any text that should have a match?
Like by:
Guyver Dark Hero
Guyver - Dark Hero
Guyver-Dark Hero

Please check query [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22EntitySearch%22%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22www.wikidata.org%22%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Asearch%20%22Guyver%3A%20Dark%20Hero%22%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wikibase%3AapiOutputItem%20mwapi%3Aitem%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FitemLabel.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201%0A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more flexible search, you can use the `Search` service instead of `EntitySearch` (see [MWAPI § Supported services](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI#Supported_services)):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Search" .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:srsearch "Guyver Dark Hero" .
    ?itemId wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title .
  }
  BIND(URI(CONCAT(STR(wd:),?itemId)) AS ?item)
  {
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424;
          rdfs:label ?itemLabel.
  }
}
LIMIT 1
```

The service's output is a page title (that on Wikidata is just an item ID), which I convert to an URI for making it referable by the other subquery.

Comment: Cool, thank you, it works!
Can you please tell if parameter
bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en"
is actually helping?
Because no matter what language I use it often returns not related language value.
For example if I search for the movie "1936 - Goalkeeper"
It returns title in Ukrainian language
I know I can add filter there for the ?itemLabel,
but I hoped to improve query performance by specifying language and expecting to get label in the same language in result.

Comment: No, that was a copypaste typo. The only accepted inputs for the `Search` service are `mwapi:srsearch`, `mwapi:srwhat`, `mwapi:srlimit`, as you can see in the documentation that I linked. Thank you for having pointed it out, I've corrected the answer.

Comment: But how can I get label in different language? 
adding SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
doesn't do any thing :(

Comment: The new query will be something like `SELECT ?itemId ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Search" .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:srsearch "Guyver Dark Hero" .
    ?itemId wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title .
  }
  BIND(URI(CONCAT(STR(wd:),?itemId)) AS ?item)
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". }
}
LIMIT 1`

Comment: Otherwise, if you want the label to be **mandatory**, you can query for `SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Search" .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:srsearch "Guyver Dark Hero" .
    ?itemId wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title .
  }
  BIND(URI(CONCAT(STR(wd:),?itemId)) AS ?item)
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 ;
        rdfs:label ?itemLabel.
  FILTER(LANG(?itemLabel)="fr")
}
LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thank you for more examples. I finally found what was wrong.
If you use " SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". } "
then you need to specify column ?itemLabel in the 
" SELECT ?itemId ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {  "
and at the same time I had " rdfs:label ?itemLabel. " defined, that was overriding itemLabel value from the " SERVICE wikibase:label  "